# Do we know that LWE is harder than Ring LWE?

Tags: lattice-crypto, lwe, ring-lwe

The plain, normal-form, decisional LWE problem over $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ is: given a *uniformly random* $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and vector $b\in \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}^n$, decide if $b=As+e$ for small $s$ and small $e$.

The decisional ring LWE problem is, in $R_q:=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(q,p(x))$, given uniformly random $a\in R_q$ and $b\in R_q$, decide if $b=as+e$ for small $s,e$.

The intuition that LWE is at least as hard as ring LWE is that we can express the ring LWE problem as a plain LWE problem by expressing $b$, $s$, and $e$ as vectors, and $a$ as a matrix, and then it is exactly an LWE problem. $a$ produces a circulant matrix $A$, which feels like it should be easier.

But this is only a proof that ring-LWE reduces to *worst-case* LWE. I want a reduction to *average-case* LWE. The same technique does not work: circulant matrices might be the hardest type of matrix for LWE. Or at least, I can't prove otherwise.

If there were an easy random self-reducibility proof for the randomness of the matrix $A$, that would give the result. But everything I know of goes through the heavy (and non-tight!) machinery of the lattice -> LWE reductions, rather than directly LWE -> LWE.

Does such a reduction exist?

Answer (score 3):

Few things: Circulant LWE is easy --- it corresponds to RLWE in $\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x^n-1)$, which (for $n = 2^k$) is (ring) isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x-1)\times \prod_i \mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x^{2^i}+1)$. In particular, one can project down onto the $\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x-1)$ component (corresponding to evaluation of the polynomial at 1) to reduce to a 1D plain LWE instance. To avoid this we instead work in $\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x^{2^{k-1}}+1)$, e.g. the largest-degree irreducible factor of $\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x^{2^k}-1)$, which corresponds to *negacyclic* (rather than *cyclic* matrices). In general, $\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(f(x))$ need not have any worst-case hardness. There are some papers on this (generally with titles that include some combination of "Provably" and "Weak RLWE").

Second, my understanding is that there is a fairly straightforward way to rerandomize the $A$ component of $(A, u)$, though the technique is not sample-preserving. This is done by letting $r$ be suitably random (generally uniform in $\{0,1\}^m$, or discrete Gaussian), and outputting $(r^t A, r^t u)$. As written this only makes sense for plain LWE, but for RLWE one can instead take random linear combinations of RLWE instances. There are some nuances here (plain LWE shows $r^t A$ is uniform by the leftover hash lemma, which is false for RLWE. Instead one needs a "regularity lemma"), but is this the kind of thing you are hoping existed?

Comment: The re-randomization you describe also inflates the error, correct? And indeed, it's not sample preserving (LWE with 1 sample is trivially hard/easy). So we could say LWE(m,n,q,chi_e) is at least as hard as MLWE(2m,n,q,chi_e/r) for some r, depending on how to do the re-randomization, but I'm wondering if there is a reduction that matches the intuition that RLWE ought to be directly easier than the corresponding LWE instance.

Comment: Yes it does. And I doubt there is anything saying RLWE is *strictly* easier, as we practically use the same attacks on both at the same cost. Any "RLWE is strictly easier in general" result should (practically) mean we have better attacks, which we don't.